# Correlation ID is lost when using Collection with ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

This is my listener

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ["cartListHashes"])
@SendTo
@Transactional
fun listHashes(token: String): Collection<String> {
    // get id
    return doListHashes(token)
}

private fun doListHashes(token: String): Collection<String> {
    val id = userService.lookupIdSync(token)
    if (id == null) {
        log.info("Cannot get user id with token $token")
        return emptyList()
    }
    return cartRepo.listHashes(id).map { base32.encodeToString(it) }
}
```

The problem is that correlation ID is lost.

> No correlationId found in reply: xxx - to use request/reply semantics, the responding server must return the correlation id in the 'correlationId' header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I cannot use Collection as return type.
In the `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter`:

```
protected void sendResponse(Object result, String topic, @Nullable Object source, boolean messageReturnType) {
    if (!messageReturnType && topic == null) {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("No replyTopic to handle the reply: " + result);
        }
    }
    else if (result instanceof Message) {
        this.replyTemplate.send((Message<?>) result);
    }
    else {
        if (result instanceof Collection) {
            ((Collection<V>) result).forEach(v -> {
                if (v instanceof Message) {
                    this.replyTemplate.send((Message<?>) v);
                }
                else {
                    this.replyTemplate.send(topic, v);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            sendSingleResult(result, topic, source);
        }
    }
}
```

Collection result will be treated as individual messages.

It works after I modified the return type to Array.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ["cartListHashes"])
@SendTo
@Transactional
fun listHashes(token: String): Array<String> {
    // get id
    return doListHashes(token)
}

private fun doListHashes(token: String): Array<String> {
    val id = userService.lookupIdSync(token)
    if (id == null) {
        log.info("Cannot get user id with token $token")
        return emptyArray()
    }
    return cartRepo.listHashes(id).map { base32.encodeToString(it) }.toTypedArray()
}
```